# MySQL version 5.6.35 RDS DB Instance crashed with error code 6

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

DB instance is running on MySQL version 5.6.35
Please see below for more details... Is it a bug in this version which needs an upgrade to a later version or there is something to look at the memory parameter tuning.

DB Instance Crashing consecutively for 2 days at the same time with the same error log as below:

```
mysql> show variables like 'query_cache_%' ;
+------------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name                | Value |
+------------------------------+-------+
| query_cache_limit            | 0     |
| query_cache_min_res_unit     | 512   |
| query_cache_size             | 0     |
| query_cache_type             | OFF   |
| query_cache_wlock_invalidate | OFF   |
+------------------------------+-------+
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "sort_buffer_size";
+------------------+--------+
| Variable_name    | Value  |
+------------------+--------+
| sort_buffer_size | 262144 |
+------------------+--------+
Sort_merge_passes=@SMP
Sort_merge_passes rate=@SMP_RATE
+------+-----------+
| @SMP | @SMP_RATE |
+------+-----------+
| 1756 |     21072 |
+------+-----------+

Logs:

2020-04-18 19:24:15 115590 [Warning] Event Scheduler: [rdsadmin@localhost][mysql.ev_rds_gsh_collector] Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'Unknown'
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  vector::_M_range_check
19:28:26 UTC - mysqld got signal 6 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed, 
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

key_buffer_size=16777216
read_buffer_size=262144
max_used_connections=416
max_threads=2000
thread_count=190
connection_count=189
It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 1065977 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 0 thread_stack 0x40000
/rdsdbbin/mysql/bin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x2c)[0x8d1a7c]
/rdsdbbin/mysql/bin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x481)[0x66eea1]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0xf100)[0x2b5e7d2ad100]
/lib64/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x37)[0x2b5e7e3485f7]
/lib64/libc.so.6(abort+0x148)[0x2b5e7e349ce8]
/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6(_ZN9__gnu_cxx27__verbose_terminate_handlerEv+0x155)[0x2b5e7db56515]
/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6(+0x5e6a6)[0x2b5e7db546a6]
/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6(+0x5e6d3)[0x2b5e7db546d3]
/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6(+0x5e8f3)[0x2b5e7db548f3]
/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6(_ZSt20__throw_out_of_rangePKc+0x67)[0x2b5e7dba6557]
/rdsdbbin/mysql/bin/mysqld[0xa95394]
/rdsdbbin/mysql/bin/mysqld[0xa96cbd]
/rdsdbbin/mysql/bin/mysqld[0xa97ec0]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0x7dc5)[0x2b5e7d2a5dc5]
/lib64/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d)[0x2b5e7e409c9d]
The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
2020-04-18 19:28:49 58516 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2020-04-18 19:28:49 58516 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2020-04-18 19:28:49 58516 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2020-04-18 19:28:49 58516 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2020-04-18 19:28:49 58516 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2020-04-18 19:28:49 58516 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2020-04-18 19:28:49 58516 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2020-04-18 19:28:49 58516 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2020-04-18 19:28:49 58516 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 117.0G
2020-04-18 19:28:56 58516 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-04-18 19:28:57 58516 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2020-04-18 19:28:57 58516 [Note] InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 16180005449622
2020-04-18 19:28:57 58516 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2020-04-18 19:28:57 58516 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2020-04-18 19:28:57 58516 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2020-04-18 19:28:57 58516 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages 
2020-04-18 19:28:57 58516 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 16180010692096
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 16180015934976
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 16180021177856
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 16180026420736
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 16180031663616
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 16180036906496
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 16180042149376
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 16180047392256
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 16180052635136
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 16180057878016
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 16180063120896
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 16180068363776
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 16180073606656
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 16180078849536
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 16180080849294
InnoDB: 3 transaction(s) which must be rolled back or cleaned up
InnoDB: in total 27 row operations to undo
InnoDB: Trx id counter is 262472787712
2020-04-18 19:29:01 58516 [Note] InnoDB: Starting an apply batch of log records to the database...
InnoDB: Progress in percent: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 
InnoDB: Apply batch completed
InnoDB: Last MySQL binlog file position 0 50483028, file name mysql-bin-changelog.344987
2020-04-18 19:29:08 58516 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
InnoDB: Starting in background the rollback of uncommitted transactions
2020-04-18 19:29:08 2bc860e82700  InnoDB: Rolling back trx with id 262472780916, 1 rows to undo
2020-04-18 19:29:08 58516 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-04-18 19:29:08 58516 [Note] InnoDB: Rollback of trx with id 262472780916 completed
2020-04-18 19:29:08 2bc860e82700  InnoDB: Rolling back trx with id 262472779752, 2 rows to undo
2020-04-18 19:29:08 58516 [Note] InnoDB: Rollback of trx with id 262472779752 completed
2020-04-18 19:29:08 2bc860e82700  InnoDB: Rolling back trx with id 262472778249, 24 rows to undo
2020-04-18 19:29:08 58516 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.35 started; log sequence number 16180080849294
2020-04-18 19:29:08 2bc907606700 InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /rdsdbdata/db/innodb/ib_buffer_pool
2020-04-18 19:29:08 58516 [Note] Recovering after a crash using /rdsdbdata/log/binlog/mysql-bin-changelog
2020-04-18 19:29:08 58516 [Note] InnoDB: Rollback of trx with id 262472778249 completed
2020-04-18 19:29:08 2bc860e82700  InnoDB: Rollback of non-prepared transactions completed
2020-04-18 19:29:09 58516 [Note] Starting crash recovery...
2020-04-18 19:29:09 58516 [Note] Crash recovery finished.
2020-04-18 19:29:09 58516 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2020-04-18 19:29:09 58516 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2020-04-18 19:29:09 58516 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2020-04-18 19:29:09 58516 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2020-04-18 19:29:09 58516 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 2 events
2020-04-18 19:29:09 58516 [Note] /rdsdbbin/mysql/bin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.6.35-log'  socket: '/tmp/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
2020-04-18 19:29:09 58516 [Note] Event Scheduler: scheduler thread started with id 1
```

Comment: there was a discussion on SO about it,maybe it helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61296889/mysql-rds-db-instance-crashed-with-error-code-6

Comment: @Wilson, I will post the details asked from the MySQL instance here as well as in the new thread. Instance class : db.m4.10xlarge vCPU : 40 RAM : 160 GB
Output for  B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; after minimum 24 hours UPTIME C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; is in the following link:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BCNUs54AOzAno0BCLjg9kzA0mUNQqsCb/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The same issue re-occurred again today around same time.

Comment: @DineshMishra How long have your been using hybris?  About 193 of the entries in SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; are attributed to hybris and most of them are sleeping.  Can you share the code used for hybris - connect - process - close request?  The SHOW GLOBAL STATUS reported 185 threads_connected when the data was saved.  The first line posted of your error log indicates something failed to provide a legitimate DOUBLE value going into mysql.ev_rds_ghs_collector which is the garbage collector for MySQL.

Comment: @DineshMishra What date was the first failure of this nature In your error log?  Approximate start date of using hybrid?  Do you know why about 13 com_flush activities are being processed each hour?  Please post a sample if it is always the same kind of flush. Do you have flexibility to Skype TALK with me?

Comment: @Wilson the first date was 17th April at 19:20ish, and followed by around same time on 18th and 19th. Also it reoccurred on 20th at 20:04 ...

Answer (score 0):

Rate Per Second = RPS

Suggestions to consider for your AWS RDS Parameters

```
innodb_lru_scan_depth=100  # from 1024 to reduce 90% of CPU cycles used for function
innodb_flush_neighbors=2  # from 1 to flush all same EXTENT activity to reduce innodb_buffer_pool_pages_dirty to minimize innodb_buffer_pool_ages_dirty count of 22,587.
innodb_flushing_avg_loops=5  # from 30 to reduce loop delay
key_cache_age_threshold=7200  # from 300 (seconds) to reduce key_reads RPS of ~ 285.
read_rnd_buffer_size=128K  # from 512K to reduce handler_read_rnd_next RPS of 1,081,907
innodb_open_files=25000  # from 4000 - should always be = table_open_cache
sort_buffer_size=512K  # from 256K to reduce sort_merge_passes RPS of 2
```

You should find reduction of CPU BUSY when these suggestions are in use.

Observations, 
    select_scan reports RPS of 1,048 - could be reduced with appropriate indexes

```
There are many more opportunities to improve your instance that is experiencing connections averaging 7 per second.
```

Comment: Please let me know the other opportunities for the improvements. Alos  let me know if there is a bug in this particular version.
I got from some where in the internet that - I went ahead and investigated the error 'std::out_of_range/vector::_M_range_check' and found that is a know issue in MySQL 5.6.35 and has been reported by 'Bug #84940 - MySQL Server crash possibly introduced in InnoDB statistics calculation'[1] which correlates to the MySQL internal Bug #24585978 - InnoDB: An error in code related to table statistics raised an assertion in the dict0stats.cc source file'[2].

Comment: And, the bug has been fixed in 5.6.36 and higher 5.6 versions."

Comment: You may reach me at skype.com  Skype ID  wlhauck@aol.com   I usually check it 3 times a day.